# How to pivot date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My query returns the following result:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is the below look by using pivot or anything.

---

### RM_ROWID | RM_DESC | H_DESC | <- Block date range here ->

I have earlier used the below syntax to achieve a different result

```sql
PIVOT(
MAX(BRD)
FOR H_DESC IN ([Merit Crystal Cove],
[M.Royal], [Merit Park], [M.R.Premium],
[Afrodite],[Other Hotels])) PVT
```

However as you can see I have hardcoded the hotel names as the hotel names are predefined. but the issue now is that the Block dates will be different for every different RM_ROWID and I can't seem to find the right syntax to make it work, any help is very appreciated.

P.S I will be calling this query from a winforms app using Entity framework
and will always pass RM_ROWID as a where condition.

Comment: If `RM_ROWID` is a primary key - I'd advice to pivot this data in application code. Mapping pivoted columns to a class is going to be difficult in EF Core.

Comment: [You should not post code/sample data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server actually has a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) function that you can use for this usecase. Please find a tutorial for this [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/)

Syntax for use is below as from official documentation:

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

If you have a problem figuring out the dimension then you could use [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to first gather all distinct dates and then use that as the IN condition.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this usecase warrants the use of the PIVOT function. You can achieve this using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT RM_ROWID,RM_DESC,H_DESC,min(BlockedDate) as min_date,max(BlockedDate) as max_date
FROM <Your query>
GROUP BY RM_ROWID,RM_DESC,H_DESC
```

I hope this answers your question.